# Move to next capital letter

Tags: vim

Is there an easy way to move to the next capital letter with vim? I'm often working with camel-cased variables and it could be useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few scripts out there to redefine the word motion commands (`b`, `e`, `w`) to stop at capital letters in CamelCase words; [camelcasemotion](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1905) looks well-established (disclaimer: I've never used it). The [Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Moving_through_camel_case_words) has a few examples of simpler scripts if you prefer to do it yourself. Here's a relatively simple way to remap `C-Left` and `C-Right` to handle caml-cased words.

```
nnoremap <silent><C-Left> :<C-u>call search('\<\<Bar>\U\@<=\u\<Bar>\u\ze\%(\U\&\>\@!\)\<Bar>\%^','bW')<CR>
nnoremap <silent><C-Right> :<C-u>call search('\<\<Bar>\U\@<=\u\<Bar>\u\ze\%(\U\&\>\@!\)\<Bar>\%$','W')<CR>
inoremap <silent><C-Left> <C-o>:call search('\<\<Bar>\U\@<=\u\<Bar>\u\ze\%(\U\&\>\@!\)\<Bar>\%^','bW')<CR>
inoremap <silent><C-Right> <C-o>:call search('\<\<Bar>\U\@<=\u\<Bar>\u\ze\%(\U\&\>\@!\)\<Bar>\%$','W')<CR>
```

Comment: +1 because using `search()` doesn't screw up your current search pattern

Comment: Accepted because of CamelCaseMotion.

Comment: More awesomness on [this page](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/10/17/vim-text-objects-the-definitive-guide/)

Answer (score 6):

The following Vim command maps the Control-t key combination (use any convenient one you wish) to the command `/[A-Z]` (followed by return), which will search for the next uppercase letter in "normal mode" (command mode). You can put this in your `.vimrc` file if you wish (minus the `:`). The `<c-t>` and `<return>` is typed as I've written them here, and Vim will understand.

```
:nmap <c-t> /[A-Z]<return>
```

Comment: +1, it works! Every capital letter gets highlighted though... I was looking for something more native but I'm not sure it exists.

Comment: @greg0ire: Yeah, that's annoying. You have the `hlsearch` option set for one reason or other. Unset it with the `:nolhsearch` command.

Comment: @Kusalananda: try `nmap <tab> :call search('[A-Z]', 'W')<CR>`

Comment: Just add `<Esc>` at the end after `<return>`